# Changing Numbers from standard form without clicking every cell- Excel

Tags: mysql, excel

I have imported a csv file from MySQL, documenting part numbers and descriptions. Some of these part numbers have values like 1234567890987654321, which is then shortened by excel to 1.23e18. Problem is, I cannot query a part with this formatted data.

Now I cannot feasibly go through every cell as there are just over 28000 of them. I have converted the row to text however this does not change the data in the cell.

The closest thing I have to a solution is deleting the cells and then undo-ing, which gets the number in a textual format but then gives me a 'number in text field' error.

Also some parts have part numbers like 12E345 which is then changed to 1200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000- you get the picture.

Very annoying...

I would like a batch process to change all the values to text format, thanks in advance.

Comment: what if you convert them to strings and put quotes around them at the time of export?

Comment: Not possible i'm afraid. I compile my table from two others that I do not have rights to change (I am an IT guy but they don't trust me with the companies livelihood). I have no access to the original table so I have to change it on the table I produce...

Comment: Try `CONCAT`ing the value with a space at the end.

Comment: You need to mark the column as `TEXT` when you do the import if that is an option.  Being able to do that depends on how you are "importing".  Here is a decent article on the issue: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba

Comment: Any ideas on how to do that in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: If the data entry was `12E23` instead of `'12E23` (note the apostrophe), you are out of luck.  The input string was already converted to a number.

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided by marmarta that should resolve the issue.

Comment: @JamieWilletts : What is displayed in the formula bar in Excel? Because even if the number is formated and appears as `12E12` it doesn't me that the value isn't stored properly (and is highly probable that the full value is in there). So the true question would be *how are you using these values to query your DB*? Do you create SQL statement via Excel formulas? via VBA? If so please provide code or formula so that we can correct it to be independent of the formatting of the cells!

Comment: @JamieWilletts : I know I asked a lot of questions, but can you explain how you import your file and how you build your query from it?

Comment: Sorry, yes. It is effectively a stock check so I put in parameters for warehouse row, position etc; a particular set of part numbers; parts with value over £x amount; or parts with under x quantity. I then export the list to a csv and it can be uploaded to the relevant stock list on our website or sent to the relevant persons within the company.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of just opening the CSV in Excel, import it with Data -> External Sources -> From Text.

You will have to first pick basic things like "delimited" format, whether first row contains headers, separator etc.

In the third part of the "Text Import wizard", you can pick data type of each column - picking Text for your columns will probably solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: This seems to work quite well, i will mark your answer as the answer and will award the bounty if there are no other answers.

Comment: You may also use the value() function in another cell to convert text to number or the text(#) to convert a number to text. Noting this here for future googlers who need an alternate.